# Javascript function scope difference

Tags: javascript, function, scope

What's the difference between this:

```
(function() {
    function func1(){
        console.log(1);
    };
    func1.prototype.func2 = function(){
        console.log(2);
    };
    window.func1 = new func1();
})();
```

and this:

```
function func1(){
    console.log(1);
};
func1.prototype.func2 = function(){
    console.log(2);
};
```

I know the first example will only create a copy of the internal function func1 and put it in the window scope, but the second example is already in the window scope. Are there any performance or advantages on using the first example?

Comment: No, `new func1()` does **not** yield a copy of the function. It yields an **object,** calling `func1` as its constructor. Also, why would you care about performance in artificial made-up cases? Only optimize when performance becomes a key issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first case can be used for encapsulation to some extent. No more `func1` objects can be created from window scope with `new func1()`. (*but as RobG says in the comments new objects can be created with `newFunc1 = new window.func1.constructor()`*)...

Sometimes several JS scripts may have functions with same name leading to conflicts. This is a sort of solution for that as the `func1` is in a scope of an anonymous function here.

It can also act as singleton design pattern (not exactly the pattern).

Suppose you are going to create a game and the game needs a single but complex `gameEngine` object.  The game engine can be accessed from anywhere but only one instance is needed. In that case you may use the first case to encapsulate the complexity of the game engine, to create only one global object and to avoid function conflicts with other outside functions....

---

The second case is the normal procedure. In the second case `func1` function (constructor) is visible and any no of objects can be created from the window scope with `new func1()`.

Comment: *window.func1* inherits a *constructor* property from *func1.prototype* which references *func1*. So in the first example, more *func1* instances can be created using `new func1.constructor()`. Unpleasant, but possible. It also means that the execution context of the IIFE that creates *window.func1* is held in a persistent closure, so uses more memory than perhaps it shoud (though probably an insignificant amount).

Comment: you mean with `newFunc1 = new window.func1.constructor()`? @RobG

Comment: Yes, `func1` resolves to `window.func1` after the IIFE has completed.

Answer (score 0):

**1st:**

- You can call these type of expression **Immediately-Invoked Function Expression.**
- The basic use of this approach is to **create** a function and then **immediately execute it.**
- And any variable declared inside this method will not be visible in the global context.

  For Example :

  ```
  // An immediately-invoked function expression.

  (function() {
      var foo = "Hello world";
  })();

  console.log( foo ); // undefined!
  ```
- You can provide accessors if you want.
- This approach can use useful in many scenario like previous answer describes and jQuery use this as a basic initiation technique to make only one object of `jQuery` visible in the context.
  See : [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) or [Learn jQuery](http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife)

**2nd**:

- This is the basic approach of creating prototypes for `Prototype (something like Object Oriented)` JavaScript.

for example :

```
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};
```

This will create a prototype of `Shape` and then add `move` method to that prototype.
See [Mozilla Site for Detail](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)